# How to set a default number and default text to send message in it in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sms

Hello friends I'm very beginner in android studio and in programming field.

I have watched a video tutorial on how to make sms app but i want to develop an app for knowing the current balance in bank account through sms by clicking on the button only. For that i have to set a default number and a default text which cannot be seen to user so only when user click on the button then automatically default message will send to that default number.

But when i try to click on it only the toast message comes sometimes sent or otherwise fail and then nothing happens. Help please!

My MainActivity.java file

```
package example.domain.windows.sbibalancechecker;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
        }
    } else {

    }

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String number = "@string/def_num";
            String sms = "@string/def_msg";

            try{
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, sms, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] 
permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case 1: {
                  if(grantResults.length<0 && grantResults[0] == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                           Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {

                      Toast.makeText(this, "No permission granted", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }return;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="161dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:text="BALANCE CHECK" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My String file

```
      <resources>
               <string name="app_name">SBI Balance Checker</string>
               <string name="def_num">09223766666</string>
               <string name="def_msg">BAL</string>
     </resources>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="example.domain.windows.sbibalancechecker">

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
 <application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
     android:supportsRtl="true"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    checkAndroidVersion();
    }
 });
```

---

```
  public void checkAndroidVersion() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        int checkCallPhonePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
        if (checkCallPhonePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
        } else {
            sendSMSMessage();
        }
    } else {
        sendSMSMessage();
    }
}
```

---

```
   private void sendSMSMessage() {
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("09223766666", null, "BAL", null, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {

  }
```

### }

```
  @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                sendSMSMessage();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SEND_SMS Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```